# Create a link with javascript within it

Tags: javascript

so I am trying to create a link within my page but for some reason it is getting disjointed the code is

```
data = data + "<li><a href='#' onclick='History.pushState({state:null},'article,"+rtndata[j].id+"','article'); return false;'>" + rtndata[j].title + "</a></li>";
```

rtndata[j].id is an id number and rtndata[j].title is a title both are being pulled from a db but when it renders in the browser it becomes

```
<a false;'="" return="" article,41','article');="" onclick="History.pushState({state:null}," href="#">Newsflash 5</a>
```

so what I to render is actually

```
<a href="#" onclick="History.pushState({state:null},'article,41','article'); return false;'>"Newsflash 5</a>;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should escape the ' characters within the onclick='' statement.

Comment: so that would be onclick=\'History.pushState({state:null},'article,"+rtndata[j].id+"','article'); return false;'\> correct?

Comment: Yeah, but Rob W. already explained it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `onclick` attribute is enclosed within single quotes. Because of this, you have to either use `"` or `&quot;` (only for values) if you have to use quotes inside the attribute.

Because your JavaScript string is enclosed within double quotes (`"`), the double quotes have to be escaped before they can be used: `"....onclick='...\"....'....";`.

To fix your code, I have decided to use double quotes (escaped) instead of single quotes:

```
data = data + "<li><a href='#' onclick=\"History.pushState({state:null},'article,"+rtndata[j].id+"','article'); return false;\">" + rtndata[j].title + "</a></li>";
```

Detailled table:

```
JS string marker     Attribute marker       Valid attribute value markers
      "                \"                   '    &quot;
      "                '                    \"   &quot;
      '                "                    \'   &quot;
      '                \'                   "    &quot;
```