# Javascript function in HTML tag generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a link with javascript within it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647716/create-a-link-with-javascript-within-it)

I am trying to put a function into HTML tag which I am generating by javascript.

What I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html = '';
    html += '<div><a href="#" onclick="showBlock("#idTextBlocks");">Show Text Blocks</a></div>';
</script>
```

The `showBlock("#idTextBlocks");` is the JQuery function which takes the ID of the component which needs to be show once the link is clicked.

```
function showBlock(id) {
    $(id).show('slow');
}
```

The problem is that it is not working. It gets generated into:

```
<a #idtextblocks");"="" onclick="showBlock(" href="#">Show Text Blocks</a>
```

I've tried to change the quotes into `'` singe: `onclick="showBlock('#idTextBlocks');` but this just breaks all my javascript.

So the question is how to correctly pass a function into HTML `<a>` tag's `onclick` attribute if the tag itself is generated with javascript?

Comment: Since you're using jQuery you shouldn't be creating your HTML that way in the first place, nor attaching your event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use `&quot;` for this:

I have come across the same issue and have fixed it by replacing `"` with `&quot;`, which is safer than using `\"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html = '';
    html += '<div><a href="#" onclick="showBlock(&quot;#idTextBlocks&quot;);">Show Text Blocks</a></div>';
</script>
```

Comment: I am waiting until I can :) Why I have to wait? It doesn't allow me to accept the answer. Still 1 minute left.

Comment: It is by default not to misuse the system of StackOverflow. :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85521/why-does-stackoverflow-make-you-wait-2-x-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47814/why-do-you-have-to-wait-8-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to to using combination of single and double quote

change

```
onclick="showBlock("#idTextBlocks");"
```

to

```
onclick="showBlock('#idTextBlocks');"
```

Instead of passing id to function you can access the required element in funciton like this,

```
function showBlock() {
    $('#idTextBlocks').show('slow');
}
```

Comment: Yes but then I will have to create three functions, because I have three links. So I'd rather pass the element's id to the function.

Comment: I've already tried single quotes. Please read the question properly.

Comment: You can't just put single quotes in a literal string delimited by single quotes. You need a backslash in front of every single quote in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery anyway:

```
var $content = $('<div/>')
  .append('<a/>', {
    href: '#',
    click: function() { showBlock('#idTextBlocks'); },
    text: 'Show Text Block'
  });
```

Now you can append/prepend `$content` wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html = '<div><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showBlock(\'#idTextBlocks\');">Show Text Blocks</a></div>';
</script>
```

Comment: Dude... Doesn't work. See it gets escaped at `'#idTextBlocks'`

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '<div><a href="#" onclick="showBlock("#idTextBlocks");">Show Text Blocks</a></div>';
```

Try to remove the + operator when inserting value in your html variable, it has nosense since you just declared html as an empty string, especially a text one. (+= operator is most oftenly used to add value to a previous value eg

```
a = 1; 
a += 2; 
alert(a) //alerts 3
```